# convert int array to string

Tags: arrays, c, type-conversion, reverse

I want to convert int array to string and reverse it (question no 2) and I can't seem to make it work and have no idea how to fix it. I used `sprintf` to convert my int array to string but it split out random numbers.

question no 2 is based on question no 1 so the getsum is still needed here

the "getsum" is for questions no 1 and 2

the picture for the question is below

the question

```
(Q.1)An integer n is divisible by 9 if the sum of its digits is divisible by 
9.
Develop a program to display each digit, starting with the rightmost digit.
Your program should also determine whether or not the number is divisible by
9. Test it on the following numbers:
n = 154368
n = 621594
n = 123456
Hint: Use the % operator to get each digit; then use / to remove that digit.
So 154368 % 10 gives 8 and 154368 / 10 gives 15436. The next digit extracted
should be 6, then 3 and so on.

(Q.2) Redo programming project 1 by reading each digit of the number to be tested
into a type char variable digit. Display each digit and form the sum of the
numeric values of the digits. Hint: The numeric value of digit is
(int) digit - (int) '0'
```

the code

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int reverse(int n) {

    char str[100];
    sprintf(str, "%d", n);
    int d = atoi(_strrev(str)); //str>int//

    int arr[100];
    int i = 0;
    int display = 0;
    char digit[100];

    while (d != 0) {

        display = d % 10;
        arr[i] = display;
        i++;
        d = d / 10;

        sprintf(digit, "%d", arr[i]);   //int>char!!!//
    }
    for (i = i - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%s\n", digit);
    }

    return 0;
}

int getsum(int n) {


    int sum = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        sum = sum + n % 10;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {

    int n;
    int i = 0;
    printf("input n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("%d\n", reverse(n));

    printf("%d\n", getsum(n));


    return 0;
}
```

[question no 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6WXO.png)

I also want to clarify that I'm new to StackOverflow in terms of asking questions, so if I did something wrong or didn't follow the required format I'm sorry :D

Comment: What is `_strrev`?

Comment: ```strrev()``` is to reverse a string e.g. 
input: 12345
output: 54321
i convert the input int to string than use ```strrev()``` to reverse the converted string then convert it back to int so i can use it to print out the reverse of the input (question 1) but question  2 requested it to be print out as string so i convert it once more from int to str but it doesnt work

Comment: Please edit the post to show that code. We need complete code as a [mre]. Also, please post the task description as text and not an image.

Comment: `printf("%s\n", digit);` having that in a `for` loop that doesn't change `digit` doesn't make sense as it will just print the same value over and over again.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, I just made the image visible. I have no idea what you mean by "changing text to image".

Comment: Ok, I think I get it, there were two edits which happened simultaneously. What I did was change the image link, not sure how it went on top of another edit. Feel free to revert my edit, in case it's not appropriate.

Comment: @kiner_shah Comment cleaner coming though - beep beep.

Comment: newb Certainly @kaylum was asking about [`_strrev()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69878787/convert-int-array-to-string?noredirect=1#comment123523035_69878787) (with a leading `_`) and not the similar named [`strrev()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69878787/convert-int-array-to-string?noredirect=1#comment123523059_69878787).  So why use `_strrev()` vs. `strrev()`?

Comment: uh I use Visual Studio (not VSC) and ```_```that is required to run the code without error. it should be the same as ```strrev()```

Comment: newb, Ah yes.  Since `strrev()` is not a standard library function,  I suspect your compiler implements the `_` version to help you know you are using a implementation specific  function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to reverse the string. Also, for converting an `int` digit to `char` digit, you just need to do `char_digit = int_digit + '0'`.

Also in your code there was a bug in the `for` loop, you should use different variable to loop (like `j`).

```
int reverse(int n) {
    int d = n, i = 0;
    char digit[100] = {0};  // will initialize digit with zeros

    while (d != 0) {
        digit[i] = (d % 10) + '0';  // '0' + 1 = '1', '0' + 4 = '4'
        d = d / 10;
        i++;
    }
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        printf("%c", digit[j]);
    } 
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to print the digits of `n` in reverse, i.e. if `n` is 2345 and you want to print 5432, then just change the `for` loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    printf("%c", digit[j]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: Hmm what if I needed it to be printed reverse?

Comment: For example, if number is 2345, you want to print it as 5432?

Comment: yes print reverse

Comment: Edited the answer, please check.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct, the line `sprintf(digit, "%d", arr[i])` overwrites the buffer `digit` each time you call it, and, therefore, you get a wrong answer in the end. You can use the return value of your first `sprintf()` which is how many symbols have been written and the hint from your task. We get

```c
// Code

int ndigits = sprintf(str, "%d", n);

// Code

char number[100];
number[ndigits--] = '\0';
while (d != 0) {
    display = d % 10;
    i++; // Now there's no need for this line. The number of digits is already
         // counted
    d = d / 10;

    number[ndigits] = display + '0'; // Use the hint
}
```

**UPD**: you can also use the `malloc()` version

```c
char *number = malloc(ndigits+1); // Add one for the null terminator

// Same code

free(number); // Free in the end
```

Comment: also thank you @kenticent for helping me too. :D